# How to fix "Page Not found" in laravel Production

Tags: php, laravel

I've deployed laravel application on a shared hosting and
I've changed the directories in index.php in public_html as well. 
The problem is that laravel wont open a view file inside a local folder, it says page not found 
For Exmaple:
 views/pages/home.blade.php , the home file wont open it will return page not found but when I move home.blade.php to views like this:
view/home.blade.php
It's working. However this case is only on sharedhosting.

This is the route controller.

...

```
public function pageRoute($page){
            return view('pages.'.$page);
    }
```

...

This is the route in web.php
...

```
Route::get('{page}',['as' => '/', 'uses' => 'DataController@pageRoute']);
```

...

This is what i'm getting when I use the route like this website.com/home

```
InvalidArgumentException
View [pages.home] not found.
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, the problem was that the actual directory name is "Panel" with capital "P" and in my code I used small letters that's why it was not found.